# How to POST a map of numbers to numbers?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The task is to save a reordered list of items.

My approach is to collect them in a sparse array, stringify and post to the server where they should be parsed and mapped to DTO field, and processed in Spring MVC controller. But my code doesn't work. Please take a look.

Front-end code:

```js
var items = [];
$.each($gridData.find("tr"), function (index, row) {
    items[$(row).data("JSGridItem").id] = index;
});

console.log("items", items);
// prints to console:
// items (6) [empty × 4, 0, 1]
// 4: 0
// 5: 1

$.post({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        map: items
    }),
    url: "/items/reordering"
});
```

Example of request payload: `map: [null, null, null, null, 0, 1]`. From this I expect to get a map of {4 to 0, 5 to 1} at back-end.

Back-end code

```java
@lombok.Data
public class ItemsOrderingDto {
    /** map of ID to order */
    @NotEmpty
    private Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
}

@PostMapping("/items/reordering")
public ResponseEntity changeOrder(
        @RequestBody @Valid ItemsOrderingDto itemsOrdering
) {
    // ... save new order
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

But I get error 400 - Bad Request.

> "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream);

For items reordering UX I use [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com/) + [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin.

Comment: declare your `items` variable as an `object` like this `var items = {};`.

Comment: @chŝdk Your suggestion is correct; I've just fixed it myself a minute ago. Please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this `Exception` because in your backend `map` is a `HashMap`/`Map<Integer, Integer>` and you are passing an `array`, while arrays aren't a `key/value` pairs data structure as expected.

The solution here is to pass an `object` instead of an `array`, so in your JavaScript side just change `items` declaration to be an `object`:

```
var items = {};
```

And you will have the expected data type.